# jQuery ajax fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/categories/?callback=?';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

And console logs error:

> index.html:25 Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}abort: function (a){var b=a||u;return c&&c.abort(b),x(0,b),this}always: function (){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}complete: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}done: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}error: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}fail: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===t?e:null}getResponseHeader: function (a){var b;if(2===t){if(!f){f={};while(b=gb.exec(e))f[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=f[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}overrideMimeType: function (a){return t||(k.mimeType=a),this}pipe: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):cf[0]+"With"})}),a=null}).promise()}progress: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}promise: function (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}readyState: 4setRequestHeader: function (a,b){var c=a.toLowerCase();return t||(a=s[c]=s[c]||a,r[a]=b),this}state: function (){return c}status: 200statusCode: function (a){var b;if(a)if(2>t)for(b in a)q[b]=[q[b],a[b]];else v.always(a[v.status]);return this}statusText: "load"success: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}then: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):cf[0]+"With"})}),a=null}).promise()}**proto**: Object

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're logging the XHR object, not the error ?

Comment: You don't need to add the callback param yourself to the URL, and you certainly don't want 2 `?` in the URL itself: `var url = 'http://localhost:3000/categories/';`

Comment: I changed my express server to send data in jsonp 'res.json()' to 'res.jsonp()' and it works now. The problem wasn't with the ajax call itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope issue may be with `contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'jsonp'`

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/categories/?callback=?';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to alter this lines..

```
cache: false, // we do not need any browser posibble caches here..
success: callback, 
// remove this line: jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
```

and ditch ?callback in the url